# How to test non-$LATEST version of AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I'm in AWS --> Lambda > Functions > myFunctionName, whenever I edit the Code and then run the Test (clicking on Test button to Left of Deploy), it is running the test on the old (deployed) version of the code. This happens whether or not I File > Save first.

This is easy to confirm by just adding a `console.log("blah");` and seeing that it does not appear in the Test output.

The Test > Execution Results also confirm the test is running on $LATEST (see bolded section):

```
Response
null

Function Logs
START RequestId: <snip> Version: $LATEST
<snip>
```

Of course I can test my version by deploying it, but isn't there any way to test BEFORE I deploy? (Sorry if this is an ignorant question - I feel I'm missing something dead obvious...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are doing it via AWS Console.

In the console, only `LATEST` is available for editing.

[image]

And for testing the function you need to deploy a version.

[Lambda function versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html)

> You can change the function code and settings only on the unpublished version of a function. When you publish a version, the code and most of the settings are locked to maintain a consistent experience for users of that version

You can test separately by publishing versions [Lambda function versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html)

You can  [Lambda function aliases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-aliases.html)
 for better handling these versions.

[Configuring functions in the console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-console.html)

Comment: Yes, AWS console. Thanks for the answer, but I guess the workflow is still a bit of a puzzle to me... I code a bit, publish a version (even though it's a draft / may still have bugs), and then test the version? Isn't that backwards? In my mind, versions are completed (debugged and about-to-be-deployed) entities. Because if I test the version, find a bug, code a bit more, make a new version, and repeat... I'll probably produce 5 versions for each version I actually want to keep / deploy. Is this intended? I guess versions can be deleted, so I can always clean-up after, but seems odd to me.

Comment: @PhilipH we deploy the code which is tested.  You can use [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) or even build a docker image and test them locally.